# How to resize a UINavigationController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a application with UINavigationController and it is appearing fine now i want to make the size of the NavigationController to a smaller size. How can i do it?

Comment: Have you found an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can resize or move the UINavigatorController if you add by code...

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            myview_view = [[[MyCustomView alloc] init]autorelease];
            ControlNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myview_view]; // Init the UINavigatorController
            ControlNav.navigationBarHidden = YES; // Hide the navigation bar
            ControlNav.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 665, 370);  // Move and resize the UINavigator Controller
            [self.view addSubview:ControlNav.view];  // Add subview
    }
```

MyCustomView is an UIViewController;

Comment: That actually only modifies the frame of the current view (myview_view in your example). As soon as you push another view the frame gets reset to full screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

According to the [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation, the only options you have to change the look are the [barStyle](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barStyle) and the [translucent](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent) properties;

> With only a few exceptions, you should
>   never modify the navigation bar object
>   directly. It is permissible to modify
>   the barStyle or translucent properties
>   of the navigation bar but you must
>   never change its frame, bounds, or
>   alpha values directly. In addition,
>   the navigation controller object
>   builds the contents of the navigation
>   bar dynamically using the navigation
>   items (instances of the
>   UINavigationItem class) associated
>   with the view controllers on the
>   navigation stack. To change the
>   contents of the navigation bar, you
>   must therefore configure the
>   navigation items for your custom view
>   controllers. For more information
>   about navigation items, see
>   UINavigationItem Class Reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also have a UITabbarController, can i resize that atleast. If so how to do it?

Comment: UITabbarController follows the same restrictions. Unless you create a custom bar controller, you can only specify the tint or the translucency of these two controls. It is mainly for UI consistency reasons.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to modify standardized interface elements. Doing so will only confuse the user. Shrinking an element makes it harder to use. I can barely hit some UI elements as it is. If you think you need to reduce the size of UI elements, your UI design is most likely overcrowded and you need to move some functionality to another view.

Comment: Ok, I down-voted and changed my mind, but it's locked.  Sorry.

Comment: @TechZen That's crap! I can come up with a bunch of ways to modify standardized interface elements without confusing the user. In some of the best rated apps the so called standardized elements has been completely rewritten. The Apple User Interface Guidelines doesn't say anything about you having to stick to standardized elements. Only general usability considerations. - If you don't know it, don't ay it.

Comment: @esbenr -- Just because you can doesn't mean you should and I said shouldn't.  Users shouldn't have to pay attention to the UI and shouldn't have to think to use it. Changing up the logical and spatial relationships forces the user to think about the UI.

Comment: @esbenr -- I think you are deluding yourself that you personally can change the UI substantially without making the user think about it. I strongly doubt that you've tested that assertion empirically. Even if you personally can just whip out a fantastic UI change, that doesn't mean that the vast majority of developers, especially novice developers can do so. Therefore, my advise to avoid making UI changes still stands.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT:** this idea sounded great in and seemed to work in theory, but the iAd framework doesn't allow you to add an AdBannerView directly to the UIWindow.  <<<<<

You can resize a UINavigationController but you cannot move the top or bottom ToolBar.

Here is an example of making a AdBanner go below your UINavigationController but above it's bottom toolbar.  This AdBanner will remain stationary in your view--it will not animated with UIViewController push and pop actions.

1) Resize your UINavigationController in the app delegate:

```
navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 410);
```

2) Manually resize the ViewControllers to add a gap below.  A good place to do this is in viewDidLoad method:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 322);
```

3) Add your AdBannerView directly to the application's window (remember it is just another UIView).  So the AdBanner would go above the toolbar, but below any visible view controllers.

```
[window addSubview:addBannerView];
```

It looks something like this:

[image]